# What are the best tests to compare the insert performance of balanced binary search trees?

Tags: avl-tree, red-black-tree

Red-black trees are often believed to perform better inserting random data while AVL trees perform much better inserting sequences of numbers one at a time since they have stricter balance requirements.  However, neither case is very realistic for using balanced binary trees.
I'm testing WAVL, AVL & Red-black tree performance in Java and need realistic test data.  What should I use?
For reference, the implementations are here:
https://github.com/dmcmanam/bbst-showdown